# Array slice doesn't seems to work

Tags: php

I'm trying to have the first file in a directory ordered by name asc. Here is the code I use (php):

```
 $dir = "fichiers/123/files_backup";
$premfic = array_slice(array_filter(scandir($dir), 'is_file'), 0, 5);
print_r($premfic);
```

But the array is empty... The directory contains 18 files and scandir alone sees them. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Woudl be useful to see your `is_file` function??

Comment: @RiggsFolly is_file is a default php function, no?

Comment: Note scandir will not return the full path to the file only the filename so filter is going to get rid of any of them that dont have a filename in the current working directory.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I made the same comment but redacted it upon a quick google search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is_file` won't work, because you're not currently in the `"fichiers/123/files_backup"`. The following should all work:

```
chdir($dir);
$premfic = array_slice(array_filter(scandir('.'), 'is_file'), 0, 5);
// You may want to chdir back to your previous directory
// You can use getcwd() before your chdir() to dynamically determine it
```

Or:

```
$premfic = array_slice(array_filter(scandir($dir), function($filename) use ($dir){
    return is_file($dir . '/' . $filename);
}), 0, 5);
```

Or as OrangePill pointed out (since glob returns the relative path, not just the filename):

```
$premfic = array_slice(array_filter(glob($dir . '/*'), 'is_file'), 0, 5);
```

Comment: Also acceptable would be `glob("fichiers/123/files_backup/*");`

Comment: @Orangepill Thanks, I've added that option to my answer as well.

Comment: `failed to open dir: No such file or directory` :-(

Comment: @user2670167 I just corrected that problem int the first version just now. It should be `scandir('.')` (**not** `scandir($dir)`) after you've switched directories with `chdir`.

Comment: Second method return `111111111111111111111`

Comment: Yes! It works with the first method and your correction ;-) Thanks a lot!